# What's an elegant way to avoid "hopping" quantization errors when graphing a divergent 2D function?

Tags: c++, qt, sampling, graphing, quantization

I have some Qt-based software that graphs an audio-transform function in 2D (with frequency-in-Hz as the X axis, and decibels-gain on the Y axis).

It does this by choosing a set of X positions to calculate points at, then calculating the Hz-value that corresponds with each X position, then calculating the dB-value that corresponds with each Hz-value, then calculating the Y value that corresponds to each dB value, and then finally drawing a series of line segments to represent the computed EQ curve.

This all mostly works well.  The exception comes when the transform I am plotting is not a well-behaved function; for example, in the video at [this link](https://public.msli.com/lcs/jaf/quantization_hopping.mov), I am plotting a "notch function" that diverges to negative-infinity at a particular value, so the mathematical function becomes infinitely-steep close to that value.

The line that is actually drawn in pixels, OTOH, doesn't always accurately represent the underlying function, in that the "spike" toward negative-infinity is often "chopped off" well above the bottom of the graph, due the limited number of points in my sampling-set.  In the video, this leads to a sort of "hopping" effect at the bottom of the white line, as I change the Notch filter's frequency control.  The ideal behavior would be if the white line would always extends to the bottom of graph, regardless of the frequency-setting, as that would more accurately reflect the underlying mathematical function.

Obviously I can reduce the magnitude of the problem simply by increasing the number of X positions at which I calculate values (up to one calculation per horizontal pixel); but that takes additional CPU cycles, and worse, it only *reduces* the visual error without ever entirely *removing* it.

My question is, are there any obvious or widely-used techniques that I could adopt to more elegantly solve this problem?  I assume that every mathematical-function-plotting program runs into this issue sooner or later; so rather than try to bodge out my own hackish solution I thought I'd first see if there is a standard-practice I could adopt.

Comment: As far as my limited math skills go, there is no absolute way to tell if any given function eventually approaches infinite: depending on the function, you can analyze its behavior and determine for which value the limit would be infinite. You're having an aliasing problem, which cannot be arbitrarily solved unless you have control over the sampling and/or you know exactly the parameters for which the function eventually reaches a peak (including infinite). In reality, you have the same problem for other values too: you don't notice them as much, but if you decrease the sampling enough, then »

Comment: » you'd see more inconsistent results of those peaks even for a function that doesn't reach infinite, than compared to the same function with higher sampling. If the purpose is only graphical, and you can have some form of "extra parameters" to the filters which will be eventually read by the plotting function, you may consider "forcing" the plot to add an intermediate "virtual sample" at the specific point (the peak).

Comment: @musicamante the "virtual sample at the peak" idea is quite good, thanks!  It doesn't work for the general case, of course, but it might be enough to ameliorate my current problem.

Comment: As said, there cannot be a valid algorithm that works for "the general case". Each math function has its peculiarities, and since visualization normally requires some level of aliasing, multiple and customized strategies must be used, which should be carefully chosen depending on the situation. In your case (and considering the audio purpose), I assume that performance is more important than accuracy of representation, since you don't seem to be using antialiased painting (or you're getting integer values for y based on screen x), so the curves don't need to be pixel-perfect accurate. »

Comment: » Still, you need good UI performance. I'm going to assume that you're using QPainterPath, QPoint based vectors or even an open QPolygon; in any case, you could iterate through each `x`, while storing them in a list/array (forgive my terminology, I'm a pythonist) and after the iteration is completed check if: 1. the function provides infinite/undefined values of `y` for `x`; 2. the list doesn't contain `x`, and in that case *insert* an arbitrary `y` between the closest `x` values. Then it's just a matter of reconstructing the final "path".

Comment: @musicamante I've done something slightly cruder than that, even; I added some logic so that when a notch filter is in use, I find the standard `x`-calculation-value that is closest to the notch filter's frequency, and move that `x` value sideways so that it exactly matches the notch filter's frequency.  Seems to work well enough for my purpose :)

Comment: Yeah, that's crude, but if it works, it works ;-) I'll think more about this tomorrow (luckily, I've got a lot of time off for these holidays); I've done some experiments and I'd like to provide an answer with some practical proposals, but I need some time to consider them with a clearer mind. As said, I'm a pythonist (I don't write C++, I can barely understand it), but I assume you won't have difficulties translating PyQt/PySide code. I've had some experience working with digital audio programming, so I believe I understand the issues you're facing and the compromises you're considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t a fully general answer here: a function could actually dance around near but above the (arbitrary) bottom of your plotting area in a complicated fashion, and no sampling scheme can discover every place it does actually diverge.  Of course, if you know the points of divergence, you can add them as plotting points (with some large finite value), but that analysis also can’t be assumed in general.

That said, there is a reasonably efficient way to handle functions that are mostly well-behaved and whose *kind* of divergences are known.  The idea is to **adapt** the graph to the function.  Often, that involves estimating the second derivative of the function numerically and adding more plotting points where it is large, but here a simpler strategy suggests itself: start with a uniform grid of points (perhaps a bit coarser than you would use by itself), and then repeatedly add points halfway between the **lowest** point not off the graph and its lower neighbor.  (You might use a priority queue to efficiently find the lowest points.)

When the separation between a point and its neighbors reaches some tolerance (about a pixel, perhaps), **disqualify** it in case a higher point in a less-explored area is near a divergence; when the lowest point remaining point is higher than another tolerance (or the total number of points exceeds yet another), stop.

Note that there are several tolerances here, as is unavoidable in attempting to heuristically capture the behavior of unknown functions.